# Error when AWS BOTO3 Connect to MS SQL Database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Please help me to modify my code when I want to connect and parse the query to RDS-MSSQL by using AWS BOTO3 python (on aws lambda)

Here is my code

```
import json
import boto3

database_name = database_name 
db_cluster_arn = db_cluster_arn 
query=query
rds_client=boto3.client('rds-data')

def execute_statement(sql):{
    print('===== Example - Simple query =====')
    response = rds_client.execute_statement(
        database=database_name,
        resourceArn=db_cluster_arn,
        sql=sql
    )
    return response

    response = execute_statement(query)
    print(response['records'])
```

[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2yMP.png)

Comment: looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found two issues. it should work if you fix those.

1. You have a `{` in the syntax in the line below:

   ```
   def execute_statement(sql):{
   ```
2. And also the line below was not indented properly.

   ```
   response = execute_statement(query)
   ```

here is the code with the fixes:

```
import json
import boto3

database_name = 'HSA_NONSAN_PROD'
db_cluster_arn = 'arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:499461857546:db:prod-hsaplus-db-2'
query='SELECT (CASE WHEN Status=1 THEN \'OK\' ELSE \'BAD\' END) AS Status FROM dbo.tbAllCustomer_NONSAN_JOBSTATUS WHERE JobRunNo=(SELECT MAX(JobRunNo) FROM dbo.tbAllCustomer_NONSAN_JOBSTATUS)'
rds_client=boto3.client('rds-data')

def execute_statement(sql):
    print('===== Example - Simple query =====')
    response = rds_client.execute_statement(
        database=database_name,
        resourceArn=db_cluster_arn,
        sql=sql
    )
    return response

response = execute_statement(query)
print(response['records'])
```